# Sequence of primes, their differences and an interesting consequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, prime-numbers

> Let's take the sequence of first $n$-th prime in their natural order for some $n\gt1$. For example:
>
> ```
>                                     2,3,5,7,11,13,17
> ```
>
> Now, take the pairwise(horizontal) difference of primes in absolute value respectively and write it down under the original sequence:
>
> ```
>                                     2,3,5,7,11,13,17
>                                     1,2,2,4,2,4
> ```
>
> Now, take the vertical difference of the sequence in absolute value respectively (discarding the lone term) then again take the pairwise difference like we did before and repeat the process as long as possible:
>
> ```
>                                     2,3,5,7,11,13,17
>                                     1,2,2,4,2,4
>                                     1,1,3,3,9,9
>                                     0,2,0,6,0
>                                     1,1,3,3,9
>                                     0,2,0,6
>                                     1,1,3,3
>                                     0,2,0
>                                     1,1,3
>                                     0,2
>                                     1,1
>                                     0
>                                     1
> ```

Like the above example, my observation is that the process always ends with $1$. Why it happens? How can I prove this? Is there any counterexample? I could appreciate any help or suggestion.

Comment: No you are wrong. The last step ends with taking vertical difference of $1$ and $0$ hence it ends with $1$, you are encouraged to check the example again. @user1952009

Comment: Horizontal difference : $u_k(n) = v_k(n+1)-v_k(n)$, vertical difference : $v_{k+1}(n) = |u_k(n)-v_k(n)| = |2v_k(n)-v_k(n+1)|$.  And $v_k(.) = 1,1,1,1,\ldots$ is a stable sequence